# Django Products model for e-commerce site

Tags: django, e-commerce, product-variations

I am trying to build  a sample e-commerce site with Django and  I am trying to figure out as to how can I model the relationship between a product having multiple sizes and each of those sizes having their individual stocks
this my products/products varied models:

```
from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
# Create your models here.



class Color(models.Model):
   
    Color = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    value =  ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Color


class Size(models.Model):
   
    Size = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Size
  

class Product(models.Model):
   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ProductVaraiant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    slug  = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    Color = models.ForeignKey(Color,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
    Size  = models.ManyToManyField(Size)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If each variant has a stock then , the stock field go in the `Variant` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  I want  to implement  an  inventory system  so for example  I have  a yellow variant of a product  this yellow  variant  is available in 3 sizes: Small, Medium, Large  and  I want  to add the number   of  products  for each size : yellow variant :S(3), M(5), L(2)

Comment: I think in that case the `ProductVariant` should have two `ForeignKey`s: one to `Color`, and one to `Size` and add an `IntegerField` to the `ProductVariant` with the number of items left in stock.

Comment: @Rvector yes but the variant has multiple sizes  i want each of those sizes having their individual stocks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so i should change the ManyToMany relation with the size model to  a ForeignKey ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given I understand the problem correctly, you should make a variant for combinations of `product`, `size` and `color`, so with `ForeignKey`s to the three other models. Furthermore you can make a `UniqueConstraint` to prevent entering the same `ProductVariant` for the color/size/product 3-tuple. The `ProductVariant` model then can also have an `IntegerField` with the number of items in stock:

```
class ProductVaraiant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_in_stock = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['product', 'color', 'size'],
                name='unique_prod_color_size_combo'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: thank you, Yes, this approach will solve the stock issue, but will make it a little bit harder in the product detail view because I will have the same color repeated for different sizes

Comment: @NAS: for a `Product` you can obtain the colors with `Color.objects.filter(productvariant__product=some_product).distinct()`, and the same for `Size`. It also makes it possible that for some colors, some sizes do not exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I am stuck in the same situation and could not figure out how to query and get distinct values of color for example. The Color model does not have product field so how can we query Color model the way you wrote Color.objects.filter(productvariant__product=some_product).distinct().
Can you please explain this a bit more, thanks.

Comment: @SohailShams: I'm not really following. Can you ask a new question with the relevant models, and *what* you aim to query?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you. Posted new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187530/django-product-variation-model-how-to-get-distinct-color